# Is it possible to detect the browser version from Django server side?

Tags: python, django

in server side, not browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `request.env` won't work.

However, you can get it through `request.META.get("HTTP_USER_AGENT")`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the HTTP_USER_AGENT in [HttpRequest](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/)

Answer (score 2):

`request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` will give the user agent string the browser sent.